# Selenium Driver timed out during get unable to accept alert authentication box

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using selenium webdriver with Java language.
I'm using a simple get methode to open a URL. This URL show me an alert authentication box, but this alert block the page loading. 
My get method throw a timeout exception and close the page, I'm unable to perform any line of code during this get method. I'm unable to handble this alert authentication box.

Is there any way to handle it?
Thanks

My code :

```
driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
app = new EventFiringWebDriver(driver);
seleniumEvent handler = new seleniumEvent();
app.register(handler);
app.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
app.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
wait = new WebDriverWait(app, 60);


app.get(URL_1);
```

I got a TimeOut exception from `app.get(URL_1);`

Comment: what is seleniumEvent? what all capabilities you are using ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for close alert authentication box you need to login to server, it's named as Base Authentification. info from Wiki:

> URL encoding

A client may avoid a login prompt when accessing a basic access authentication by prepending username:password@ to the hostname in the URL. For example, the following would access the page index.html at the web site www.example.com with the secure HTTPS protocol and provide the username Aladdin and the password OpenSesame credentials via basic authorization:

https://Aladdin:OpenSesame@www.example.com/index.html

so you can do like this:

```
try {
        driver.get("https://" + userName + ":" + password + "@" + YOUR_URL.split("https://")[1]);
    } catch (UnsupportedCommandException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Can't login to server occur error!!!", e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  public class A {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("url here");
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        try {
            if (wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent()) != null) {
                driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss();
            }
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Java says - `org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.WebDriverWait(WebDriver driver, long timeOutInSeconds)`. Why can't we have 10 here?

Comment: Hi, My page quit when it gets timeout Exception then I have " org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for alert to be present "

Comment: Can you try the updated code now please? Please ensure you are putting it at the right place where alert pops up.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this,

```
try {
      app.get(URL_1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
        Alert alert = webDriver.switchTo().alert();
        alert.accept();
    }
```

It will handle Alert in Catch block if webpage get Alert while opening it.

Comment: Hey, My page quit when it gets timeout Exception. When the catch block is called, my page is already closed

Comment: @Delfalso Can you please debug it, so you will find where exactly you are stuck. And you need to handle it accordingly.